# Код в цикле работает не так как ожидалось

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```
for (var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
        var rating = ratings[i];
        var url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${data.Search[i].imdbID}&apikey=5f85f0e7`;
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            rating.innerHTML = data.imdbRating;
        });
    }
```

Я использую omdb api где получаю imdbID для того чтобы получить рейтинг фильма.Есть 10 фильмов для которых нужно 10 рейтингов для этого я и использую цикл.Цикл получает и видит все рейтинги ,но вставляет рейтинг только для последнего фильма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: а зачем делать `fetch` в цикле? Нельзя один раз сделать `fetch`, получить массив данных и с этим работать?

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам разобрался надо было let вместо var поставить

Comment: вы делаете 10 раз лишние запросы к ресурсу, у которого берёте данные, вам следует один раз сделать запрос и всё.